# Does the sex of main character influence the game?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Does choosing a male or female character influence the gameplay or the story in some way?

Comment: Might be hard to answer, before someone has completed the game.

But I would presume that it wont influence in any major way. Mostly what is said to you and so on.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There are two perks that are affected by your interaction with the opposite sex:

1. The *Allure* perk in the *Speech* tree, which [Xenox mentioned](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34983/does-the-sex-of-main-character-influence-the-game/34998#34998), that gives you 10% better prices with members of the opposite sex.
2. Completing *The Heart of Dibella* will grant you the *Agent of Dibella* perk, which will give you a 10% melee damage bonus against members of the opposite sex.

Comment: Given the male:female ratio in past elder scrolls games, this looks like blatant sexism against men! We demand more female baddies!

Comment: But as a woman, you'll have to suffer through all the *"Yes, I know being a woman is hard, but you'll learn how to live with it"* remarks by the NPC's. Also blatant sexism? :')

Comment: historical realism... in a game where you shoot fireballs and fight dragons

Answer (score 19):

Yes, it does. For example, there is a perk (Allure) which decreases the price of items when trading with persons of the other sex.

Answer (score 0):

as i have done two complete run toughs of the game using a bot male in female character in both run through of the game i can conclude that using a female character is easier because of the allure  perk which allows discounts when trading with the opposite sex mainly because most shop keepers are female
(I hope this answered your question to the fullest of capability have a good day)